# Limit connections per user using FreeRADIUS

Tags: freeradius

I'm here because after a good time searching how to limit the simultaneous connections of a user with FreeRADIUS I haven't achieved it...

My intention is that each user connects only once and that when they try to access again with that account, if it is already in use, it does not allow them to connect to the network, but I do not find how to do it??

Answer (score 3):

If you are authenticating your users from a database, just insert this to the **radreply** table for each user:

username = "ABC"      *i.e the username of the user*

attribute = "Port-Limit"     *i.e Radius attribute for limiting simultaneous* connections

op = ":="                   *i.e The radius operator*

value = "1"                 *i.e The number of simultaneous connections you want to allow for the user*

[See how it looks on my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8KJm.png)

[You can read more about Port-Limit here](https://freeradius.org/rfc/rfc2865.html#Port-Limit)

[You can read more about Radius attributes here too](https://freeradius.org/rfc/attributes.html)

Port-Limit Attribute: *This Attribute sets the maximum number of ports to be provided to the user by the NAS. The value you set for this attribute will be sent by the server to the client in the Access-Accept packet*